# List all contacts that don't have an Attachment with given Title SOQL

Tags: soql

iIs it possible to list all Contacts that don't have an Attachment with given title 'X'?

Or select Contacts without Attachments at all?

New to SF, making integration to find contacts with missing attachments.

Already tried to do something with CombinedAttachments, but it isn't possible to directly query this object:

```
 SELECT RecordType,ParentId
 FROM CombinedAttachments AS S 
 WHERE S.Title!= 'Title.pdf'
 AND S.RecordType = 'Attachment'
```

Appreciate any help

Update: Tried to do it with 2 Queries:

```
SELECT ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE Name= 'Title.pdf' AND Parent.Type = 'Contact'
```

And then

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id NOT IN ('0031t00000bR27WAAS',...Results from previous query')
```

But got an error Bind variables only allowed in Apex code

I am using an external service to access Salesforce data, so Apex isn't the best solution. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Did my answer help? If it did can you accept it and vote up please?

Comment: @fred - community etiquette is to not solicit for answer acceptance unless OP acknowledges in a comment that your answer was what they needed and need guidance on how to mark answers as accepted. There are a bunch of threads on Salesforce Meta that go over this

Comment: @cropredy thanks, I will avoid doing so in the future. I did try to find out whether that was acceptable but I couldn't find any definitive answer. It is frustrating when users do not even respond to say whether your answer helped them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second query is fine:
`SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id NOT IN ('0031t00000bR27WAAS')`

It looks as if there is a syntax error in your `IN` clause. Make sure it is of the format `('Id1','Id2')` for all the Ids.